# Android spinner dialog style

Tags: android, colors, background, spinner, drawable

How do I adjust Spinner dialog style?

All I want to do is to change the background, either to drawable or a color.

Answer (score 1):

If you want change the spinner's popup background, you can use : `setPopupBackgroundResource()`

For change background of the spinner (not the popup), this tutorial are good -> [link](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57)

Comment: `setPopupBackgroundResource()` is available since API level 16 so definitely it won't work for me. The question remains - how to change the background?